# Como hago para que al haber un insert nuevo en la BD, se muestre automáticamente ese dato con PHP?

Tags: php, ajax

Tengo una web, en la que contiene una tabla, donde toma los datos de la BD. Quiero que esta tabla, actualice los datos constantemente, ya que ingresan nuevos datos todos los días. Lo que hice fue agregarle esta función:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var pageRefresh = 6000; //6 s
setInterval(function() {
refresh();
}, pageRefresh);
});

function refresh() {
$('#contenido').load(location.href + " #contenido");
$('#Contador').load(location.href + " #Contador");
}
```

Lo que hace es cargar la tabla, funciona perfecto. Pero me limita a modificaciones, por ejemplo. La tabla tiene un checkbox, el cual hace un update según estado, para mostrar si fue "entregado" o no. Y al hacer el load este cada 6s, me quita el check, aunque los datos los traiga de la BD. Lo que creo que me solucionaría el tema, sería insertar el último dato ingresado en la tabla automáticamente, pero sin tener que estar haciendo el load de toda la tabla. Pero no sé cómo hacerlo :/ Si pudiera solicitar una ayuda, os agradeceré!

Tabla:

```
        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
    ?>
    <tr>
            <td>
            <input type="hidden" class="id-datos" name="ID" value="<?php echo $row[6] ?>">
            <?php if ($row[7] == 1): ?>
            <input class="habilitar task-chk" name="habilitar" type="checkbox" checked >
            <?php endif;?>
            <?php if($row[7] == 0): ?>
            <input type="checkbox" class="habilitar task-chk" name="habilitar">
            <?php endif; ?>
            </td>
            <td><?=$row[0]?></td>
            <td><?=$row[1]?></td>
            <td><?=$row[2]?></td>
            <td><?=str_ireplace($serv_regular, $serv_nueva, $row[3])?></td>
            <td class="datos-td"><?=str_ireplace($desc_regular, $desc_nuevo, $row[4])?></td>
            <td><?=$row[5];?></td>
    </tr>
```

**EDIT**:

Probe con algo de Ajax, que fui recopilando info en internet, ya que desconozco del tema. Esto pude armar:

```
funcion actualizar(){

$.ajax({

    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    async:true,
    url: 'index.php',
    success: function(respuesta) {
      $('#contenido').html(respuesta[0]);
   }
})
}
setInterval( function(){
actualizar();
  },6000)
```

Pero al actualizar, me desaparece la tabla de la web.. alguna sugerencia?

Comment: ¿Por favor podría especificar lo de checkbox? Según lo que tengo entendido es que usted tiene un checkbox que hace función de si un producto ha sido entregado o no, pero el checkbox no le aparece correctamente cuando debería de salir `checked`. ¿Es eso correcto?

Comment: El checkbox al darle clic, lo pone en "entregado" (checked) y hace un update a una columna de la tabla en la BD. Para mantener el checked al actualizar la web.  Si yo actualizo desde F5, funciona perfecto. Pero con la función que tengo para "actualizar" la tabla, no me funciona el checked . Por eso preguntaba si hay alguna otra forma, por ejemplo, que cada vez que la BD reciba un nuevo dato, me lo agregue en la tabla, arriba del último dato ingresado, pero sin actualizar toda la tabla de la web, no sé si me especifico bien.

Comment: Será más simple realizar esto usando Ajax o la nueva API Fetch de Javascript.

Comment: investigo sobre Ajax o la API, ya que desconozco del tema.

Comment: Cedano, tendras algun ejemplo de Ajax?

Comment: agregue un edit, con AJAX, pero no me funciona bien.